# Multiple Rest calls in Java using RestAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

When you make a rest request using RestAssured, it appears to wait for a response. I need to make a POST request in RestAssured and then while it waits for a response, I need to make a GET request. I'm using Java and RestAssured. I've also tried creating a second thread and it still has not worked. This is for testing purposes.

Here's where it waits:

```
given().auth().preemptive().basic(userCreds[0], userCreds[1]).contentType("application/json;").and().post(baseURL + resourcePath + this.act.getId() + "/run");
```

I would like this to run while the previous request is running as well (asynchronous request?):

```
given().auth().preemptive().basic(userCreds[0], userCreds[1]).when().get(baseURL + resourcePath + this.connect.getId() + "/outgoing/" + fileId);
```

I've also read that RestAssured supports asynchronous requests, but I've been unsuccessful to get it to work. My project is mavenized. I'm just a lowly QA guy so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I read up on this some more, I think what I'm looking for is actually considered parallel, not asynchronous. I need the POST request sent, then the GET sent just after the POST is sent/requested, so I suppose they're more like parallel requests? If it helps, I'm using TestNG as my test harness.

Answer (score 1):

Completable Future can be used to make calls async.

```java
List<CompletableFuture<Pair<String,String>>> futures =
    Arrays.stream(endpoints)
        .map(endpoint -> restCallAsync(endpoint))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Pair<String,String>> result =
    futures.stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
CompletableFuture<Pair<String,String>> restCallAsync(String endpoint) {
    CompletableFuture<Pair<String,String>> future = CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<Pair<String,String>>() {
        @Override
        public Pair<String,String> get() {
            Response response = given()
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .get(endpoint)
                .then()
                .extract().response();
            LOG.info("Endpoint : " + endpoint + " Status : " + response.getStatusCode());
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @TT, This is code snapshot for my private repository.

Comment: Hi Amrit. Better to post the code as text instead a picture. Pictures cannot be searched and indexed from search engines.

Comment: Sure @TT will keep this in mind going forward, but this isn't copied from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

RestAssured support only parallel running, not asyncron running.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to do what you are planning to do using threads.

```
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(<number of threads>);

    // send 1st 7 requests here
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    given().
                        contentType(<>).
                        header(<headers>).
                        body(body).
                    when().
                        post(<URL>);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Wait for all the threads to gracefully shutdown
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(<Your timeout>);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        LOGGER.error("Shutdown interrupted. Will try to shutdown again.", ie);
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
```

Though this won't be asynchronous, this will do what you were planning to do.

Comment: Do I have to use the same number of threads in method `newFixedThreadPool()` and in `for`-loop?

Comment: @VitaliiPlagov No, you need not. They can be different based on your use case of whether you want to run it in caller's thread or a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using TestMG so write both request in separate test methods and run test in parallel using XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="3" parallel="methods" >
<test name="testGuru">
<classes>
<class name="Test_class_name">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```